# How to retrieve the url of an image in an Android app?

Tags: android

I realized that sometimes the content displayed in an android app is basically just a webpage. While one can use the inspect option in PC browsers like Chrome to find out the url of an image, is there a similar tool to retrieve the url of an image in an Android app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an app sniffer like [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en_US), it will capture all the http call ougoing. No need to root yuor phone.